# How to add Spring to new Java Project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I have Eclipse with m2 plugin and want to make new project with Spring.
In maven central repo are only Spring 1.x and Spring 2.x versions and adding http://maven.springframework.org/milestone to pom.xml don't change anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I the central repository there are also the latest final Spring artifacts (3.0.5.RELEASE).

E.g. http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.0.5.RELEASE

If you need milestones for 3.1 you should add repository definition to your pom.xml as follows:

```
<repository>
    <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
    <name>Springframework Maven Milestone Repository</name>
    <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
</repository>
```

And then you can define the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.M2</version>
</dependency>
```

There is also repository containing snapshots (nightly):

```
<repository>
    <id>spring-maven-snapshot</id>
    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    <name>Springframework Maven SNAPSHOT Repository</name>
    <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: ok I see. I looked at org.springframework spring group (here are 1.x and 2.x only), not spring-core or spring-beans (there are also 3.x)

Comment: @ql5: This is because since Spring 3 the standalone spring.jar artifact has been discontinued and you have to compose your dependencies from the artifacts you need e.g. spring-jdbc, spring-tx and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you want to use springs own repositories, but you need to add them in your settings.xml file (~/.m2/settings.xml), not in the pom.xml in your project.

```
<repository>
    <id>repository.springframework.maven.release</id>
    <name>Spring Framework Maven Release Repository</name>
    <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>repository.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
    <name>Spring Framework Maven Milestone Repository</name>
    <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>repository.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
    <name>Spring Framework Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
    <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: One can add these to a specific pom.xml as well.

Comment: When I make 'Rebuild index' I got "Unable to update index for springsource maven repo|http://maven.springframework.org/milestone"

Comment: Not sure about the indexes, but it should still be able to download artifacts